# cannot find symbol DaggerAppComponent, Cause: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-2

I was trying to build my Dagger2 based Android project in Android studio Arctic fox 2020.3.1 with Mac M1 and I got the error,

error: cannot find symbol
import xxxx.com.xxxx.di.DaggerAppComponent;
^
symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent

which also was showing

Cause: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

The same project was working in another machine(not mac).

Also I am unable to see the compiler error toggle button in android studio build output.

Please help me to resolve this.

complete build output,

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /projects/Android/prototype

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:injectCrashlyticsMappingFileIdDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dataBindingTriggerDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> The following annotation processors are not incremental: dagger-android-processor-2.16.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.16), dagger-compiler-2.16.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16).
> Make sure all annotation processors are incremental to improve your build speed.
> /Users/sysadmin/Documents/projects/esp32/energy-monitor/Android/prototype/app/src/main/java/prototype/com/myapp/ui/provision/PairingActivity.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
> import prototype.com.myapp.di.DaggerAppComponent;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
> location: package prototype.com.myapp.di
> /Users/sysadmin/Documents/projects/esp32/energy-monitor/Android/prototype/app/src/main/java/prototype/com/myapp/ui/provision/ProvisionActivity.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
> import prototype.com.myapp.di.DaggerAppComponent;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
> location: package prototype.com.myapp.di
> /Users/sysadmin/Documents/projects/esp32/energy-monitor/Android/prototype/app/src/main/java/prototype/com/myapp/ui/splash/SplashActivity.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
> import prototype.com.myapp.di.DaggerAppComponent;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
> location: package prototype.com.myapp.di
> /Users/sysadmin/Documents/projects/esp32/energy-monitor/Android/prototype/app/src/main/java/prototype/com/myapp/ui/appliance/AddApplianceActivity.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
> import prototype.com.myapp.di.DaggerAppComponent;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
> location: package prototype.com.myapp.di
> /Users/sysadmin/Documents/projects/esp32/energy-monitor/Android/prototype/app/src/main/java/prototype/com/myapp/ui/appliance/event/AddEventActivity.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
> import prototype.com.myapp.di.DaggerAppComponent;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
> location: package prototype.com.myapp.di
> /Users/sysadmin/Documents/projects/esp32/energy-monitor/Android/prototype/app/src/main/java/prototype/com/myapp/ui/welcome/WelcomeActivity.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
> import prototype.com.myapp.di.DaggerAppComponent;
> ^
> symbol:   class DaggerAppComponent
> location: package prototype.com.myapp.di
> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> 6 errors

> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
29 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 28 up-to-date

Comment: Usually, when Dagger component is not found, it means the build failed elsewhere and ended on Dagger not being generated, can you share the full build output?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan, updated the Qn with details

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to comment but I have not enough reputation, anyway, are you using room in your project? I had the same issue also only on my Mac M1, it was caused by the room version, I updated it to 2.4.0-alpha03 and it builds fine since then. if not, you may want to check the version of the libraries you are using, but yeah only on Mac M1, hope it helps.